# Matplotlib - Fit all the subplot in an A4 format

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to arrange 6 subplots in one A4 portrait format. I am using the following code:

```
variables = ['NEE', 'Qle', 'Qh', 'SoilMoist', 'LAI']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27,11.7)) #to get A4 portrait format
for i, variable in enumerate (variables):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((5,1), (i,0))
    if variable == 'NEE' or variable == 'Qh' or variable == 'Qle':
        plt.plot(x,obs,c="black")
    if variable == 'LAI':
        plt.plot(df2['median'], c='blue')
    if variable == 'SoilMoist':
        plt.plot(time_ctr_ch, ctr_soil, c='lightsteelblue')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
```

This provides all the plots to fit in a A4 format. But unfortunately, a lot of space is still unused, as you can see in the following figure:

[image]

How can I make sure that the different subplots have the same size and occupy most of the space available in the A4 portrait format?

Comment: any help with `figure.set_size_inches(11.69,8.27)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this will provide me a A4 landscape format. That's why I am using the line ´fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27,11.7))´ at the beginning of my code

Comment: yes, landscape, because witdh of the picture is greater then height. For me, it would be logical to rotate images for 90 degrees ergo use landscape style. Can you print this image and see how much space is on left and right side, if you have printer?

Comment: The fact is that I need thos plots in A4 portrait format :)
And even If I use ´figure.set_size_inches(11.69,8.27)´ I end up having unused space also

Comment: idk, not able to help you then, maybe save all 5 figures, open ps/illustrator or something and add them next to each other.. i know it's retarded solution, but it's pretty easy :)

Comment: :) thanks put I have 1000 of plots, I can't use illustrator manually :)

Comment: Is there any reason you are creating space for 6 subplots but only using 5?

Comment: @DavidG. Ok you found the mistake... That's why a lot of space was unused...Sorry I should have re-re-re-read my code before posting

Comment: Even with this code rectification I still end up with a lot of unused spaces...why?

Comment: Why not use `plt.subplots` with `gridspec_kw` parameters as-needed?

Comment: Replace `plt.subplots_adjust(...)` by `plt.tight_layout()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This essentially comes down to, why is the following line not working:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
```

If we follow what matplotlib is doing:

`plt.subplots_adjust` calls [`Figure.subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) under the hood. This then updates [`figure.SubplotParams`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.SubplotParams.html#matplotlib.figure.SubplotParams) which itself calls a function called [`update`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.SubplotParams.html#matplotlib.figure.SubplotParams.update). If we look at the [source code](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/figure.html#SubplotParams.update) there is a handy docstring:

```
def update(self, left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None,
           wspace=None, hspace=None):
    """
    Update the dimensions of the passed parameters. *None* means unchanged.
    """
```

So because you are passing `None` to the arguments of `subplots_adjust` you are not actually changing the values from their default (which are controlled by the matplotlibrc file)

Therefore, you need to actually give float values for the arguments, something like:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.05, right=0.95, top=0.95, wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

Alternatively you could use [`plt.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html)